# How does one prove that some points on a circle have different perpendicular distances from a 3D line?

Tags: geometry

[image: lin]

So take the set up I have in the picture. The circle is on the plane of sheet and the pen I am holding in my hand is analogue to a line in 3-d space. Now I need to prove that the perpendicular distance from the line to the circle on the sheet is different  for each point on the circle.

ANother phrasing:
a pen is parallel to a plane sheet of paper. how does one prove that not every point on the circle is the same distance (perpendicular to the pen's axis) from the pen?

Edit: **I do not mean perpendicular distance from plane. I mean perpendicular distance from axis of the pen. Treat the pen as a cylinder. and take the central axis of it**
Please comment if more clarification is needed

Comment: It isn’t necessarily true.

Comment: There are cases where that is not so. For example, if the pen is parallel to a circle diameter.

Comment: But I need a mathematical proof. In the case I have shown , would it be thrown? yes or no? treat the pen as a cylinder and consider the line passing through the center as axis

Comment: You can't have a mathematical proof for a statement that is not true.  I think in all cases there will be many pairs of points that are the same distance from the line.  The suggestion from Weather Vane certainly works.

Comment: I need help for this very specific case... no other can do

Comment: @RossMillikan Can there be a disproof? Here the line is parallel to plane of circle

Comment: This statement is not true in the case in the image, I am not sure if there exists a case where this is true.

Comment: How do I disprove it then?

Comment: A case for true: pen and circle are parallel. Pen projection on circle is tangent to it.

Comment: Are you sure you're including the full problem?

Comment: This problem came as a sub problem from a physics problem me and my friend were doing. I am trying to argue that each point on the circle is not same radial distance from the axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of all points equidistant from a line in 3-D space is a cylinder. There is no way to draw a plane such that the intersection of the plane and the cylinder is a circle, unless the cylinder's axis and the plane are perpendicular (in which case the line goes through the circle's center). So, there is only one special case where all points on a circle are equidistant from a line in 3D space.

Note that it's not true that *all* points on the circle are different distances from the line. For any orientation, the intersection of the cylinder and the plane will consist of an infinite number points. As long as the circle passes through two of those points, you do not have the case that "the perpendicular distance from the line to the circle on the sheet is different for each point on the circle". Pairs of points on the circle will be equidistant from the line - in fact, the only points which are unique in their distance from the line are the single nearest/farthest points.

Comment: I think this answers my question

Answer (score 0):

If the line is parallel to the plane of the circle, consider the plane perpendicular to the line that passes through the center.  Now consider two planes parallel to the given plane that are an equal distance (less than the radius of the circle) on either side.  Those planes will each cut the circle in two points.  If you take the close point of each pair, they are the same distance from the line.

To take a specific example, let the circle be in the $xy$ plane, centered at the origin, of radius $1$.  Let the line be $x=z=1$, which is parallel to the plane of the circle.  The plane through the center is the plane $y=0$.  The two planes can be $y=\pm \frac 12$, for example.  One plane cuts the circle at $(\frac {\sqrt 3}2,\frac 12,0)$ and $(-\frac {\sqrt 3}2,\frac 12,0)$.  The other plane cuts the circle at $(\frac {\sqrt 3}2,-\frac 12,0)$ and $(-\frac {\sqrt 3}2,-\frac 12,0)$.  The points $(\frac {\sqrt 3}2,\frac 12,0)$ and $(\frac {\sqrt 3}2,-\frac 12,0)$ are equidistant from the line, as are the points $(-\frac {\sqrt 3}2,\frac 12,0)$ and $(-\frac {\sqrt 3}2,-\frac 12,0)$

Added in light of the change in the question:
If the line is not parallel to the plane of the circle, consider the two planes perpendicular to the line such that the intersection with the plane of the circle is tangent to the circle.  One tangent point will be closer than the other.  If the line is parallel to the plane of the circle, consider the plane perpendicular to the line through the center and the planes one radius on either side.  The three planes will cut the circle in four points which will not all be the same distance from the line.  The only way the two on the plane through the center are the same distance away is if the line passes through a line perpendicular to the circle and passing through the center.  Then the other points will be closer.

Comment: you have proved two points have distance. I'm trying to say to prove that there are points with different distances 
Please check edit

Comment: That is quite a different question from the original one.  Did you look at the comments to see where your original one failed?  Now we want two points at different distances, not to show that all pairs of points have different distances.  Getting the question right is the first step in getting the right answer.

Comment: yes I need to show that there at least two points on the circle which have different distance from that "pen" which is line

Comment: This was what I had in mind originally but I was finding very difficult to word. English is not my first language